# Unable to set Border using pseudo :hover class

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set border of textbox using css but i am unable to do it. Here is my code:

```
<input type="email" id="email" style="display:inline-block;margin-top:10px;width:180px;height:30px;border:1px solid #cccccc;border-radius:1px;padding-left:8;padding-right:8;">
<style>
#email:hover
{
box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(192,192,192,0.4);
border:1px solid #bbbbbb;
}
</style>
```

But when i specify no border in inline css and then try to set border in :hover pseudo class then it works. Like this:

```
<input type="email" id="email" style="display:inline-block;margintop:10px;width:180px;height:30px;border-radius:1px;padding-left:8;padding-right:8;">
<style>
#email:hover
{
box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(192,192,192,0.4); 
border:1px solid #bbbbbb;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use an `!important` in your CSS rule:

```
#email:hover
{
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(192,192,192,0.4); 
    border:1px solid #bbbbbb !important;
}
```

As inline CSS always overwrites non-`!important` rules.

---

But I encourage you to not use such a big inline styles and write it into a `<style>` block or better into an external file as it makes it easier to overwrite your rules without `!important`:

```
#email {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:10px;
    width:180px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius:1px;
    padding-left:8;
    padding-right:8;
}

#email:hover
{
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(192,192,192,0.4); 
    border:1px solid #bbbbbb;
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much. I tried it before but it wasn't working now it worked. Thanks again!

Comment: @Madeyedexter Just added some content to my answer; I hope it may help you structuring your CSS better.

Answer (score 2):

Inline CSS has higher precedence than a stylesheet/style tag precedence. One way to work around this, which is not recommended, is to change your `<style>` style to this:

```
<style>
  #email:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(192,192,192,0.4); 
    border: 1px solid #bbbbbb !important;
  }
</style>
```

`!important` will override any other style definition.

Answer (score 2):

because the inline `style` is give most importance.
if you want any other rule to overpower your inline style, use `!important`

```
 #email:hover
   {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(192,192,192,0.4);
    border:1px solid #bbbbbb;!important
  }
```